splitting string into new columns different criteria in R
I have 2 different nomenclatures and want to split the patient ID and timepoint
Original dataframe



patient_id_and_timepoint




12345 V1


101-123-V1



Desired dataframe



patient_id
timepoint




12345
V1


101-123
V1



sampledata <- df %>%  mutate(timepoint=case_when(str_detect(patient_id_and_timepoint,  " V")~str_split_fixed(df$patients_id_timepoint, ' ', 2), str_detect(patients_id_timepoint,  "-V")~str_split_fixed(df$patients_id_timepoint, '-V', 2)))

We can try using strsplit() here:
df <- data.frame(patient_id_and_timepoint=c("12345 V1", "101-123-V1"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$patient_id <- apply(df, 1, function(x) strsplit(x, "[ -](?=V\\d+$)", perl=TRUE)[[1]][1])
df$timepoint <- apply(df, 1, function(x) strsplit(x, "[ -](?=V\\d+$)", perl=TRUE)[[1]][2])

df
patient_id_and_timepoint patient_id timepoint
1                 12345 V1      12345        V1
2               101-123-V1    101-123        V1

The regex pattern used here says to match:

[ -] a space or hyphen
(?=V\\d+$) lookahead and assert that what follows is V, followed by
an integer, followed by the end of the string


thank you, but this does not work, it pastes the same patient id over and over only works for one of the nomenclatures, "12345 V1" but not "101-123-V1"

No, it works for both sample data points.

it does not. when i run your solution on the df, I get "12345 V1" twice. can you please check

You were correct; I did not test on an actual dataframe.  Try the updated answer which uses apply() in row mode.

Another idea would be to use the separate function from the tidyr package. I reused the really neat Regex pattern proposed by @Tim Biegeleisen.
library(tidyverse)

original <- tibble::tribble(
  ~patient_id_and_timepoint,
  "12345 V1",
  "101-123-V1"
)

expected <- original |> 
    tidyr::separate(
      patient_id_and_timepoint,
      into = c("patient_id", "timepoint"),
      sep = "[ -](?=V\\d+$)")

